# eq(0) is not a valid selector with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select class="qty">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<select class="qty">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

I have 2 `select` tags and I want to update them with an array. This means changing the selected to correct value, but why in my attempt below is `:eq()` not working with my loop?

```
selectedArr = [2,3];

$.each(selectedArr,function(i,obj){
    console.log(obj);
    $('.qty:eq(' + i + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com. A lot of your questions could be solved with 2 minutes of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things wrong here:

1. `$('.qty:eq('+i+')').prop('selected',true)` is only setting the `selected` property on the `<select>` element - *not* the `<option>` element
2. You aren't selecting the appropriate option from the array according to `selectedArr`

I would do something like this:

```js
var selectedArr = [2, 3];

$.each(selectedArr, function(i, obj) {
  $('.qty:eq(' + i + ')').val(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="qty">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>


<select class="qty">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, I always forget that

Answer (score 3):

Need space its is descendant selector

```
$('.qty option:eq('+i+')').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: This would select `1` and `2` respectively. I think OP wants to select the options from the `selectedArr` array

Comment: @RGraham - I just denote what The OP mistake is??

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to modify the `selected` property of the `select` elements. You should select their target `option` child and then modify the `selected` property. `HTMLSelectElement` object has no `selected` property.

The following snippet at first selects the target select element based on the index of the current iteration and then select the target option element:

```
$.each(selectedArr, function (i, obj) {
    $('.qty:eq(' + i + ') option:eq('+ obj +')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Another option is using the `val` method:

```
$.each(selectedArr, function (i, obj) {
    $('.qty:eq(' + i + ')').val(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/p9z1xsed/)**

As you don't have value attribute in options, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
selectedArr = [2, 3];
$.each(selectedArr, function (i, obj) {
    console.log(obj + '' + i );
    $('.qty:eq(' + i + ') option:eq(' + obj + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
selectedArr = [2,3];

$.each(selectedArr,function(i,obj){
    console.log(obj);
    $('.qty option').eq(i).prop('selected',true);
});
```

Comment: Why? What's the difference between this and the original code?

Comment: @RGraham obviously `option`

Comment: The difference is that you don't have to manually append the index to the string. To maximize the use of the plugin.

Comment: @NeilVillareal I didn't see the addition of the `option` selector, apologies

Comment: @RGraham that's fine :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/4wfeqd2z/

```
selectedArr = [2,3];

$.each(selectedArr,function(i,obj){
    console.log(obj);
    $('.qty').each(function() {
        $(this).find('option:eq('+obj+')').prop('selected',true);
    });
});
```